# php error when trying to echo an image from an external URL

Tags: php, html, url

[image: Image With Explanation]

Inside this picture it explains it a little better, but basically In the html column, I need to have the players Avatar from an External URL Placed next to the users name. But I cant seem to get it to work I figured I would ask here because this community is rather helpful Here's the code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('REMOVED', 'REMOVED', 'REMOVED'); 
mysql_select_db('stats');

$query = "SELECT * FROM stats"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "<tr><td><img src="'. "https://crafatar.com/avatars/" . $row['uuid'] .
 '">" . $row['name'] . "</td>";  
 echo "<td>" . $row['PLAYER_KILLS'] . "</td>";  
 echo "<td>" . $row['MOB_KILLS'] . "</td>";  
 echo "<td>" . $row['DEATHS'] . "</td>";  
 echo "<td>" . $row['DAMAGE_DEALT'] . "</td>";  
 echo "<td>" . $row['DAMAGE_TAKEN'] . "</td>";  
}



mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will interpolate variables in brackets, so you can escape the quotes in the `src` tag and then enclose your variables in `{}`:

```
echo "<tr><td><img src=\"https://crafatar.com/avatars/{$row['uuid']}\">{$row['name']}</td>";
```

No concatenation required, the code is much cleaner. Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1dc7ee2fd22d2561db3c69ee607f8621d91e4dc).

The result is:

```
<tr><td><img src="https://crafatar.com/avatars/42">foo</td>
```

**WARNING**

***You should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely enclose them

Comment: my apology I'm new here I'm not exactly sure how everything works around here yet, thanks again! PS. Changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo "<tr><td><img src=\"https://crafatar.com/avatars/\"" . $row['uuid'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
```

Use `\"` to escape `"`